# Count Duplicate Values SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Say I have the below dataset

```
ID|  Last   |  FavColor
-------------------------
1 | Johnson |  BLUE
1 | Johnson |  RED
2 | Thomas  |  YELLOW
3 | Anderson|  BLUE
3 | Anderson|  RED
3 | Anderson|  BLUE
4 | Phillips|  ORANGE
4 | Phillips|  ORANGE
```

How do I create a query that still keeps the ID, Last and FavColor, but shows a occurrence count of each color?

```
ID|  Last   |  FavColor |  Color Count  | 
-----------------------------------------
1 | Johnson |  BLUE     |        1      | 
1 | Johnson |  RED      |        1      | 
2 | Thomas  |  YELLOW   |        1      | 
3 | Anderson|  BLUE     |        2      | 
3 | Anderson|  RED      |        1      | 
3 | Anderson|  BLUE     |        2      | 
4 | Phillips|  ORANGE   |        2      | 
4 | Phillips|  ORANGE   |        2      |
```

I attempted to do a COUNT(FavColor) PARTITION BY(ID), but am not sure how to count duplicates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to partition by id as well as favcolor:

```
SELECT ID,
  Last ,
  FavColor,
  COUNT(*) over (partition BY id, favcolor) color_count
FROM your_table t;
```